# Filters and FilterProvider with Dependency Injection; Manage Per-request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have been experimenting with Unity and a customer `Filter` / `FilterProvider`. My concern is that the classes are never disposed. Here is a code example i started with:

```
//FilterProvider
public class CustomFilterProvider: IFilterProvider
    {


        public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {

            if (actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<CustomAuthorizeAttribute>().Any())
            {
                var filter = UnityinstanceLocator.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<CustomAuthorize>();
                yield return new FilterInfo(filter, FilterScope.Global);
            }
        }
    }

//Filter
public class CustomAuthorizeFilter: IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IFakeService _fakeService;

        public CustomAuthorizeFilter(IFakeService fakeService)
        {
            _fakeService = fakeService;
        }


        public bool AllowMultiple { get; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
        {
           ...Do Some stuff
        }     
    }

 //Attribute
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute
    {

    }
```

My `IFakeService` implements `IDisposable`. I set this up as a test. My unity registration for the `IFakeService` makes use of the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`. I never see it being disposed when it is inside a filter. Injecting the `IFakeService` into the controller works as expected.

The startup for the filter provider looks like this (I am using OWIN):

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration {DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityinstanceLocator.GetConfiguredContainer())};
config.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider), new ComceptFilterProvider());
```

I suppose I could go old school and wrap my disposable class in a `using` statement inside the `ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync` method and avoid Dependency Injection all together. Is there a better solution to this if I were to stay with Unity?

Comment: How about injecting a FakeServiceFactory and using that to create a FakeService - which you can use in a using block where you actually use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebApi framework filters are cached. So they are [singletons](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filter-attributes-are-singletons) and reused across requests. Instance of your `CustomAuthorizeFilter` never be disposed during lifetime of application and keeps reference to `IFakeService`.

Comment: Until I am ready to moving to .Net Core and use the [ServiceFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.servicefilterattribute) I'll have to settle for a simpler solution and use my underlying context directly without DI.